# JQuery Animate : Change the destination of a prop during the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, mouseevent

I made a image scrolling with the mouse.

The image scroll to a position based on the mouse position percentage of the window height.

```
$(imageContainer).mouseenter(function(e){
    var scrollingTo = ((e.pageY/$(this).height())-.083) * ( $(imageContainer).prop('scrollHeight') - $(imageContainer).height() );
    hijacked = true;
    $(imageContainer).animate({scrollTop:scrollingTo},300,function(){hijacked=false;});
}).mousemove(function(e){
    if(hijacked) return;
    var scrollingTo = ((e.pageY/$(this).height())-.083) * ( $(imageContainer).prop('scrollHeight') - $(imageContainer).height() );
    $(imageContainer).scrollTop(scrollingTo);
});
```

So. in that line

```
$(imageContainer).animate({scrollTop:scrollingTo},300,function(){hijacked=false;});
```

I want that scrollingTo change. Because during the animation, the user can move the mouse, changing the scrollingTo variable.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly: you want to dynamically alter the animation based on how the mouse moves during the animation?

Comment: yes, that's it. I want to alter the destination point during the animation

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I managed to cook together a hacky way of dynamically altering an animation. My understanding of the internal animation queue for jQuery is not great, but as far as I know there's no way to alter a queued animation, other than to make it stop. Anyway, here's the key code for an example that alters position, which should be adaptable to scrolling (in [fiddle form](http://jsfiddle.net/zDY48/5/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last_update = 0;
    $(document).on("mousemove", function (e) {
        if (Date.now() - last_update > 50) {
            $mover = $("#mover");
            $mover.stop(); 
            $mover.animate({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY}, 200, "linear");            
            last_update = Date.now();
        }
    });                    
});
```

There were a couple of tricks to make it work, I'll go through them and try to explain how I believe they could be adapted to scrolling:

- The main idea is that on mousemove, the prior event is cancelled, and a new one is started.
  I don't believe this will require any changes for scrolling.
- Some forms of animation accelerate/decelerate over the course of the animation - it's too hard to preserve this in a constantly changing animation (at least without writing a custom animation function), so the animation easing is set to "linear".
- rapidly changing animations takes time (especially for an event as common as mousemove), so there's a limit on how often the animation can change. Before a change to the animation is made, it's ensured that no changes have been made in the last .05 seconds (this is done with "last_update").

I believe if you just swap out the animation properties for your own (scrollTop), this should do what you're looking for.

Comment: I was trying to do something similar myself and ended up on a similar solotion. Only I use an Interval instead of comparing times inside the mousemove event. Also you don't need to call .stop() if you use the queue:false option like in my answer, it improves performance a little. Like this:  $mover.animate({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY}, {duration:200, easing: "linear", queue: false});